# How to correctly test that expressions match after a delayed assignment?

Tags: verilog

I have a circular buffer controlled by head and tail variables:

```
reg[BITS:0] head;
reg[BITS:0] tail;
```

At some point there is

```
tail <= tail+1;
if (tail+1 == head)
  // do something
end
```

In case tail+1 overflows and wraps around this if statement isn't triggered. I think that the reason is that "tail+1" isn't automatically rounded to BITS+1 width.

What is a proper way to write such code that the "tail+1 == head" would be computed with values of width BITS+1 as it would be done in the hardware that this code describes?

Comment: there is simply not enough code in your code sample to analyze. you need to provide at least use of always blocks. You can have multiple issues with this code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, here is that `+1` is interpreted as `+32'sd1` (a signed 32-bit number). You need to create an operand so that extra bits are not added

```
parameter [BITS:0] one = 1;
```

Then the result of `(tail+one)` remains at BITS+1 width.

In SystemVerilog you can use a simple cast `BITS'(tail+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can mask expressions:

```
parameter MASK = (1 << (BITS+1)) - 1;

// ...

if (((tail+1) & MASK) == (head & MASK))
    // do something
end
```